# Attach query string to results

Tags: sql, sqlite

When doing a sql query with something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE 'searchstring';
```

Is there a way to attach the query string, here 'searchstring' to the results?  I ask because in this case

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%searchstring1%' OR column1 LIKE '%searchstring2%';
```

you can get multiple rows back in the result, and you may not know which rows go with which query string.

Is there a way to attach the query strings to their associated rows in another column? For example,

```
result_col1 result_col2     searched
a              b         searchstring1
c              d         searchstring1
f              g         searchstring2
```

Comment: Can you reword your question? What do you mean by *attach query string to their associated rows* ?

Comment: Just added some text. I mean attach a new column with each query string

Comment: updated with an example of what I meant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the searchstring as a column in your query and obtain them in your results:

```
SELECT 'searchstring' AS querystring, * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%searchstring%';
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to do this if you are searching for multiple strings using e.g., `OR`? For example: `SELECT 'searchstring1' AS querystring, FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%searchstring1%' OR column1 LIKE '%searchstring2%';`

Comment: You can add as many query strings to the query as you like:SELECT 'searchstring1' AS querystring1, 'searchstring2' AS querystring2 FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%searchstring1%' OR column1 LIKE '%searchstring2%';

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't quite work as that just adds more columns. I need one column with each row associated with the result for that searchstring.

Comment: You can use a result code system to track the condition that your results satisfy: `SELECT CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%searchstring1%' THEN 1 WHEN column1 LIKE '%searchstring2%' THEN 2 END AS resultcode, * FROM table1 WHERE column1 LIKE '%searchstring1%' OR column1 LIKE '%searchstring2%';`